# How To use grep in a chain as an alias

Tags: linux, bash, alias, aliases

```
cdl ()   
{  
   cd $1  
   ls
}
```

So I use the above in my bash_aliases file by running `cdl /lib/systemd/systemd`.

My question is how can I add grep to this. I'd like to be able to do something *like* `cdl [/path] [grep query]`

maybe something like

```
cdlg ()   
{  
   cd "$1"
   ls | grep -ni
}
```

Comment: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Just an observation — those are not aliases; those are functions.  Aliases are more limited in what you can do with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
cdlg ()   
{  
   cd "$1"  
   ls | grep -ni "$2" -
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work ```[skinnx86@Skinnx86-EOS system]$ ls -l | grep 'nordvpn'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  227 Jan 11 20:39 nordvpnd.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 Jan 11 20:39 nordvpnd.socket
[skinnx86@Skinnx86-EOS system]$ cdlg /lib/systemd/system nordvpn
grep: nordvpn: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you try: cdlg /var/log/ "sys"

Comment: yeah same output. no file found

Comment: It works in a test I have done on my machine, using other dirs, and search targets. Maybe try `...grep -ni "$2" -`. The `-` makes it explicit to "read-from-stdin". Good luck.

Comment: well what do you know, I restarted my my machine and it worked. Something tells me that simply running `. ~/.bashrc` wasn't doing the trick.  Should of used `source ~/.bashrc`.  Or restart my machine.  -- Thanks everyone :-)

Comment: `. file` and `source file` are 100% equivalent — the second just involves more typing, that's all.  (See GNU Bash manual [Bourne shell builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) and [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-source).

Comment: I'd recommend using `-e "$2"` rather than just `"$2"` because if you decide to look for `-rwxr-x-wx` permissions, for sake of example, without the `-e`, `grep` will interpret those as options and will complain about unknown options.  Yup, you could look for `^-rwxr-x-wx` and it would work; also, my whole example is not entirely relevant because you use `ls` and not `ls -l`, but the gist remains relevant — using `-e "pattern"` ensures that the pattern is interpreted as a pattern, whereas omitting it can cause the pattern to be misinterpreted.